# How to auto-login website in chrome-mobile with saved password on a Android tablet

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile-chrome

Know anyone a why or app to autologin in a website on google chrome mobile [android tablet]? Chrome is auto-filling the credentials, but dont log in in until with click login. How to automate? 
I have a autostart app, which start chrome and a website after start and now i need a autologin on this website!

Comment: Try localStorage.Store users info on first login into localStorage.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
Validate users info from localStorage and perform automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of LocalStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("username", "Smith");
localStorage.setItem("pass", "***");
```

Then fetch the credentials from localStorage and perfom validation

`localStorage.getItem("username");
-----`

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)